# Primefaces : Highlight validation not working in dynamic datatable

Tags: validation, primefaces, datatable, highlight, bean-validation

i don't understand why highlight for bean validation not working in this datatable. I try a lot of thing as put dialog in/out form , update each component, ...

Thank you for helping.

```
<h:form id="defaultPlanningValueForm" styleClass="generalSize">
                <p:dialog id="defaultPlanningDialog" widgetVar="defaultPlanningDialog" header="Valeur par défaut des cours" showEffect="clip" 
                          hideEffect="clip" resizable="no" modal="true" class="planGenDialogDefault">
                    <p:dataTable id="planningDataTable" var="plan" value="#{planningController.defaultValuePlannings}" resizableColumns="true" rowStyleClass="planGenRow">

                        <p:column headerText="Unité de formation" class="planGenDefaultHeaderOut">
                            <h:outputText value="#{plan.organizedUt.ut.name} - #{plan.organizedUt.level}"/>
                        </p:column>

                        <p:column headerText="Professeur" class="planGenDefaultHeaderTeacher">
                            <p:selectOneMenu id="defaultTeacher" value="#{plan.person}" styleClass="dialogTeacherComboBox" class="planGenDefaultComboTeacher">
                                <f:selectItems value="#{plan.organizedUt.teachers}"/>
                            </p:selectOneMenu>
                        </p:column>

                        <p:column headerText="Local" class="planGenDefaultHeaderRoom">
                            <h:inputText id="defaultRoom" value="#{plan.room}" required="true" 
                                         requiredMessage="Entrer un local pour pour #{plan.organizedUt.ut.name} - #{plan.organizedUt.level}" 
                                         class="planGenDefaultRoom"/>
                        </p:column>

                        <p:column headerText="Heure" class="planGenDefaultHeaderHour">
                            <p:inputMask id="defaultStartHour" value="#{plan.startHour}" mask="99:99" required="true" 
                                         requiredMessage="Veuillez entrer une heure pour #{plan.organizedUt.ut.name} - #{plan.organizedUt.level}" 
                                         converterMessage="Veuillez entrer une heure valide pour #{plan.organizedUt.ut.name} - #{plan.organizedUt.level}" 
                                         class="planGenerateDefaultHour">
                                <f:convertDateTime type="time" pattern="HH:mm" timeZone="CET"/>
                            </p:inputMask>
                        </p:column>
                    </p:dataTable>

                    <h:panelGrid id="eventDetails" columns="1" class="planGenValidateButton">
                        <p:commandButton id="validateDefaultValue" value="Valider" actionListener="#{planningController.generateSchedule()}" 
                                         update="defaultPlanningValueForm defaultPlanningDialog defaultRoom defaultStartHour :messages" icon="ui-icon-check" oncomplete="PF('myschedule').update();"/>
                    </h:panelGrid>
                </p:dialog>
            </h:form>
```

Comment: When you say "highlight validation" you mean the colour of error fields doesn't change? Have you tried it without that "generalSize" styleclass that you've defined on the `<h:form/>`?

Comment: Hello, yes i tried without this style. Yes, the color doesn't change, for more precision i'm speacking about the red border of the field.